# How to solve the gradle error of "Could not read PGP secret key"?

Tags: gradle, code-signing, gradle-plugin

I'm using GnuPG to sign my jar before publishing to sonatype nexus central.

Here is the definition file:

```
subprojects {

    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/66352905/1772342

    val signingKeyId = providers.gradleProperty("signing.gnupg.keyId")
    val signingKeyPassphrase = providers.gradleProperty("signing.gnupg.passphrase")
    signing {
        useGpgCmd()
        if (signingKeyId.isPresent && signingKeyPassphrase.isPresent) {
            useInMemoryPgpKeys(signingKeyId.get(), signingKeyPassphrase.get())
            sign(extensions.getByType<PublishingExtension>().publications)
        } else {
            logger.info("PGP signing key not defined, skipping signing configuration")
        }
    }
```

When I run the following command:

```
gradlew publishToSonatype \
  closeSonatypeStagingRepository \
  -PsonatypeApiUser="..." \
  -PsonatypeApiKey="..." \
  -Psigning.gnupg.keyId="E1D4CD2CE69ED220" \
  -Psigning.gnupg.passphrase="..." \
  "${@}"
```

I got the following error:

```
> Task :core:signMavenPublication FAILED
:core:signMavenPublication (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':core:signMavenPublication'.
> Error while evaluating property 'signatory' of task ':core:signMavenPublication'
   > Could not read PGP secret key
```

This error is very strange, as the PGP secret key can be easily fetched in my OS by the `gpg` command, yet gradle still complain not being able to find it

What should I do to make gradle doing the right thing?

The main project is visible here:

https://github.com/tek/splain/blob/7a2d3829516896337627f9b214ab0c8eb1f66aa3/build.gradle.kts